# Custom Conditions To Filter Users In Jquery/Php/Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

im building a tool to send out emails to my user base. I want to create a dialog where users can create clauses to filter the users they want to send to. I.e.

"User who **registered** **before 08/08/15**" - which is pretty easy to do in a mysql query

But I want to let the user combine clauses to further filter users. I.e.

"User who **registered** **before 08/08/15**" and

"User who **of group** **2**"

My question is, what is the most efficient way to get the right users? It is pretty easy to translate those two example conditions into a mysql query, but I dont know how I can keep the query flexible to basically take unlimmited clauses to work.

Sth. like

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
    id
    FROM users
    WHERE regDate > ?
    AND usergroup = ?
    ");
```

But regDate and usergroup are variable ofcourse depending on what the users clause says.

So again, the question is not how to translate a clause into a query but more how I insert a various amount of "where" clauses into a query in a dynamic way. **Basically how to integrate a variable amount of "AND" clauses in a prepared statement.** Hope you understand^^

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `str_to_date`

```
 SELECT 
    id
    FROM users
    WHERE regDate > str_to_date('08/08/15','%d/%m/%y')
    AND usergroup = '2'
```

Comment: thanks but thats not the issue. Its about how i can add a various amount of "AND" clauses to a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but I have used this structure in a parameterized query before to apply filters to search results. The basic principle is that once you have cleaned and validated your input you loop through it and assign it to your query while keeping it parameterized. WHERE 1=1 exists purely to avoid a conditional statement and a "reverse" LIKE is used to get the match i.e. WHERE 'Jack,Jill,Jason' LIKE '%'+FIELDNAME+'%'

```js
//Assumed recieved conditions below

$filters = array(
  'brands' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
  'colours' => array('a', 'b', 'c');
);

$params = array(
  $_SESSION['Member_ID'],
  $category_id
);

$sql = "select * from dbo.GetFrontEndProducts(?,?) where 1=1 ";
if (count($filters['brands']) > 0) {
  $sql. = " and ? like '%' + Brand_Name + '%'";
  array_push($params, implode("','", $filters['brands']));
}
if (count($filters['colours']) > 0) {
  $sql. = " and ? like '%' + Colour + '%'";
  array_push($params, implode("','", $filters['colours']));
}

$sql. = " ORDER BY ITEM_ID OFFSET convert(int,?) ROWS FETCH NEXT convert(int,?) ROWS ONLY";

//execute
```

Comment: Hey just posted the non prepared version. Might be interesting for you aswell as it should work and is a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks for the head up. Nice approach... Nifty use of implode.

Answer (score 0):

This would propably be the non prepared version... But want the prepared :(

```
$andArray = array();
if($clause1 != "") $andArray[] = "regDate > {$regDateCond}";
if($clause2!= "") $andArray[] = "usergroup = {$usergroupCond}";

$whereStr = implode(" AND ", $andArray );

$query = "Select * from users WHERE {$whereStr}";
```